# Moving a div with animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click

I'm looking to move a div "#menu" to the side when it's clicked on.  I'm using this code

```
  <script>
    $("#menu").click(function(){
        $("this").animate({ 
            marginLeft: "+=250px",
        }, 1000 );
    });
    </script>
```

but it doesnt seem to do anything, I dont even get a cursor when I hover over it.  What am I doing wrong here? I'm sure this is a simple fix that I'm just overlooking.

Comment: Try using `$(this)` - without the quotes. When you use the quotes it's as if you are trying to match a `<this></this>` element :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `$(this)` (without quotes).

```
$("#menu").click(function(){
  $(this).animate({ 
    marginLeft: "+=250px",
  }, 1000 );
});
```

When you use it with quotes it's as if you are trying to match a `<this></this>` element on your document. I'm fairly sure that's not what you want :)

Answer (score 1):

```
 $("this").animate({ 
        marginLeft: "+=250px",
    }, 1000 );
```

should be changed to:

```
 $(this).animate({ 
        marginLeft: "+=250px",
    }, 1000 );
```

"this" -> this

Comment: whats the difference from the comment?

Comment: @sipp That seemed wrong to you buddy, our answers had 10-15 secs difference and i even upvoted his answer.

Comment: Yeah my end was showing his answer mins ago and yours seconds ago but now its showing it much closer

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove quotation marks $(this).